# XNA Monogame effective draw primitives

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm new in Monogame (OpenGL).

I want to draw 10.000+ primitives, just rectangles.

```
public class RectangleObject
{
    public BasicEffect Effect { get; set; }
    public Matrix PointTranslation { get; set; }
    public Matrix PointRotation { get; set; }
    public Matrix PointScale { get; set; }
    public VertexPositionColor[] VerticesList { get; set; }
    private VertexBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private Game game;

    public RectangleObject(Game game)
    {
        this.game = game;

        Effect = new BasicEffect(game.GraphicsDevice) { VertexColorEnabled = true };
        VerticesList = new VertexPositionColor[4];

        vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(game.GraphicsDevice, 
                                        typeof(VertexPositionColor), 
                                        VerticesList.Length, 
                                        BufferUsage.WriteOnly);

        vertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(VerticesList.ToArray());
        game.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
    }

    public void DrawRectangle()
    {
        Effect.World = PointScale * PointRotation * PointTranslation;
        Effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
        game.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(
                          PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, 
                          VerticesList, 
                          0, 
                          vertexBuffer.VertexCount / 2);
    }
}
```

I want to rotate/translate/scale each rectangle object, because each object have 3 matrices.
Application is loading content creating 100*100 grid of RectangleObjects and in Draw() method I'm calling DrawRectangle() method of RectangleObject.
When I try to draw 50*50, it keeps 60FPS. But if I try to draw 10.000 rectangles, application running with 15-25FPS.

Attached dotTrace log:
[image: dotTrace log]

The questions are:

- Is this effective method to draw objects?
- There I can increase performance of application?
- Could you give me links, where I can read about performance?

Comment: Monogame isn't _"OpenGL"_ by the way, it's a spin-off of _XNA_

Comment: Monogame has two backends, as I know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281599/opengl-or-directx-monogame-template-for-porting-to-windows-8-phone

Comment: That's the backend.   You don't write OpenGL code in the same way as you don't write D3D

Comment: MickyD, of course I guess you're right. I just wrote exactly information about how I use Monogame, including information about backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your game is re-sending the same geometry each frame to the GPU whether the geometry was changed or not (which from what you have said should be static).    Also I think you would benefit from **indexed primitives** for performance reasons (see below).

According to [Riemer](http://www.riemers.net/), you should call `SetVertexBuffer()` prior to calling `DrawIndexedPrimitives()`:

> With that being done, you only need to instruct your graphics card to fetch the vertex and index data from its own memory using the **DrawIndexedPrimitives method instead of the DrawUserIndexedPrimitives** method. Before our call this method, **we need to let your graphics card know it should read from the buffers stored in its own memory**: [Tell me more...](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/VertexBuffer_and_IndexBuffer.php)

e.g. (from Riemer)

```
 device.Indices = myIndexBuffer;  // <------------- NEW
 device.SetVertexBuffer(myVertexBuffer);
 device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList,  //
                              0, 
                              0, 
                              vertices.Length, 
                              0, 
                              indices.Length / 3);
```

Note the use of `DrawIndexedPrimitives`.  I recommend you investigate that over `DrawUserPrimitives`.  Note also you'll need to change your code to use indices.

Don't call `game.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer)` in your `RectangleObject()` constructor.  I can't think of a reason you should ever do any GPU alteration in such objects.  Do so in your `drawxxx()` methods.

### Conclusion

With these changes you'll have the performance of what is essentially VBO vs your current, what the GPU is currently considering as a "dynamic" VAO.

<s>You can achieve great performance by using instancing of the same geometry rather than having the same geometry multiplied out 10,000 times.</s>

### Tell me more

- Riemer, *"Improving performance by using VertexBuffers and IndexBuffers"*, http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/VertexBuffer_and_IndexBuffer.php, retrieved 2016/7/23

Comment: As a note, instancing is not yet supported on all MonoGame platforms... including OpenGL, though support for that is pending.

Comment: @PetriLaarne Whoops! I new that. Thanks  :)